# Customized Publications/Reference Style

Tags: biblatex, biber

I want to mimic the following reference style for my CV using `biblatex`:

> ***Conference Publications:***
>
> **[C1]** “The title of my paper”
>
> **Author1**, Author2, and Author3
>
> USENIX Symposium on Networked Systems Design and Implementation **(NSDI)**, 2018
>
> (40 out of 252 submissions, acceptance ratio: 16%)

In details:

1. The first line being the title of the paper using a unique numeric identifier in Bold.
2. The second line: The name of the authors while highlighting my name.
3. The name of the venue or conference with the name of the conference being in bold
4. Some notes about the acceptance rate.

So is it possible to do that with `biblatex` using Biber as backend?

**Edit:**

So far this is the Style I got using the below code:

**Output:**

> Author Names. 2017. “PaperTitle”. In: Conference Title.

**Code:**
I use awesome-cv template which requires Biber abd XeLatex compiler

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{awesome-cv} % A4 paper size by default, use 'letterpaper' for US letter

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=publist, plauthorhandling=highlight, nameorder=given-family, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\plauthorname[FirstName][]{LastName}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}

\makecvheader % Print the header

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Publications]

\end{document}
```

**Biblio File:**

```
@inproceedings{ref1,
    author = {Authors},
    title = {Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Conference Name},
    series = {Conference'17},
    year = {2017},
    publisher = {ACM}
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far? How does you `.bib` file look like? What bibliography style do you use for the other entries? An [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) can get us get started more quickly.

Comment: @moewe Please check my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired format requires a full re-write of the bibliography driver.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=publist, plauthorhandling=highlight, nameorder=given-family, maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\plauthorname[FirstName][]{LastName}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@inproceedings{ref1,
    author = {FirstName LastName and Anne Elk and Elena Ditor},
    title = {Paper Title},
    booktitle = {Conference Name},
    series = {Conference'17},
    year = {2017},
    publisher = {ACM},
    addendum = {40 out of 252 submissions, acceptance ratio: 16\%},
} 
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{inproceedings}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{title}%
  \printunit{\newline}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{author}%
  \printunit{\newline}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+booktitle}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{event+venue+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printlist{organization}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
    {\printfield{isbn}}
    {}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \printunit{\newline}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[title=Publications]
\end{document}
```

[image]